# How do I disable git subtree pull if nothing is new

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a git repository **subtools** that I handle through [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree) inside my main project **sf-parent**.

I have a problem with the following command

```
git subtree pull -P subtree/subtools subtools v3.0.3 --squash
```

`v3.0.3` is a git tag.

The problem is that the command never tells me that nothing's new to pull, however is pulls anyway and thus adds new commits to my **sf-parent** project.

This is very weird because it hasn't happen before.

How do I tell [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree) to pull only if something's changed?

**UPDATE**

Maybe should I leave `git subtree` and use `git read-tree` instead?

Comment: So if I repull a tag my subtree already 'sits' on, I get:"Already up-to date". It creates a merge commit, thats true. Is this what grinds your nerves?

Comment: Can you fetch instead of pull?

Comment: @evolutionxbox AFAIK there is no `git subtree fetch` actually...

Comment: @ckruczek I expect to get "Already up-to-date" so nothing is going to change. But instead I get new merge commits...